# Vector Interpolation in Higher Dimensions

Tags: multivariate-analysis, interpolation

I have a collection of vectors $\mathbf{X}^{(i)}$ that live in a space of dimensionality $N$. I would like to construct a curve that interpolates through those points in a **nearest neighbour fashion** (i.e. each point is only connected to the its closest two points). The curve should form a closed loop and any point in that curve should be parameterised by a single parameter (e.g. the length of the curve up to that point).

The curve doesn't need to be smooth. The collection is not ordered. **The only properties that this curve should have are (1) it should pass through every point once, (2) it should be parameterised by a single scalar (e.g. [0,1]).** The curve should act as a map from $ℝ$ to $ℝ^{N}$. I don't want a minimum spanning tree since this is not one-to-one.

The collection of vectors $\mathbf{X}^{(i)}$ trace a multivariate distribution. The ultimate goal is for me to able to produce new vector-points in that distribution by providing a scalar argument. This process should be deterministic (not random sampling).

Something like the figure, but in higher dimensions:

[image]

Are there any algorithms/methods that satisfy the aforementioned conditions? Ideally, I'd want something that can be implemented efficiently in Python.

**Update**

I found out the following references:

https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~dfg/AndysSplineTutorial/Parametrics.html
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686464/how-to-construct-a-parametric-cubic-b-spline
https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-INT-global.html

The proposed solutions seem to be exactly what I need. Do you know if there's a public python package that implements such a method?

**Something like scipy.interpolate.BSpline but for high-dimensional spaces would be exactly what I seek.**

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're looking for.  A Euclidean minimum spanning tree?  A solution to a traveling salesman problem?  A spline?  Is your collection ordered by the index $i$ or not?  What properties should this curve have (besides being continuous, one-to-one, and closed)?  What is the intended application of this mathematical problem?

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question--but reluctantly, because I still find it very broad. There are just too many possible solutions.  (Splines of any order; Kriging; and Traveling Salesman are three approaches that immediately come to mind.  And most of them can be varied by permuting the data.)  To focus the question and get better answers, consider stating the intended statistical application.

Comment: How can any one those methods (e.g. splines, GPs, traveling salesman) act as a map from $ℝ$ to $ℝ^{N}$. As far as I know, none of them can act as a single-parameter curve.

Comment: Connecting each point to its two nearest neighbors will not necessarily give a connected graph. So, this is inconsistent with your later two conditions. On the other hand, the two conditions can be trivially satisfied. For example, list the points in any arbitrary order. Then, connect each pair of adjacent points in the list, as well as the first and last points. The curve then interpolates between connected points in any fashion. This is unstructured and probably useless, which suggests that you may need to add further constraints to the problem.

Comment: If you provide more background on why you want to do this, we could help you come up with a better solution.

Comment: Composing any curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with the canonical projection functions $\pi_j:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ (which return the $j^\text{th}$ coordinate) yields $n$ functions $\gamma_j=\pi_j\circ\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}.$ This is called a "parametric" form of the curve. The problem thereby reduces to (a) choosing a permutation $X^{(i_1)},\ldots,X^{(i_k)}$ of the points; (b) choosing a sequence $0=t_0\lt t_1\lt \ldots \lt t_{k}=1;$ and (c) for each $j$ fitting a curve to the data $(t_0,X^{(i_k)}_j),(t_1,X^{(i_1)}_j),\ldots,(t_{k-1},X^{(i_{k-1})}_j),(t_k,X^{(i_k)}_j).$

Comment: Re your latest edit: `scipy.interpolate.BSpline` already does the job, as I explained in the preceding comment.  Just apply it separately to each component of your data.  For working, illustrated examples with $n=2$ (in `R`) see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24929/664 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37078/664.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to choose a random point $x_0$ to start, this is $t=0$.  Choose another random point $x_1$.  This is $t=1/N$ where $N$ is the size of your dataset.  We can interpolate between these two so that, for $0<t<1/N$, we take $f(t) = Ntx_1 + (1-Nt)x_0$.  This gives a linear interpolation between the two points.  Repeat this process until you've exhausted your points and returned to the original point $x_0$.  In general, for $i/N \leq t \leq (i+1)/N$, we have

$$f(t) = (Nt-i)x_{i+1} + (i+1-Nt)x_i$$

One can see that at $t=i/N$, $f(t) = x_i$, so $f$ passes through every point.  Take $x_N := x_0$ to get a closed loop.

This loop is closed, although if some points happen to coincide, it won't be a simple one.

Comment: If you want a "small" loop, just choose nearby points instead of random ones for your favorite definition of "nearby"

Comment: The general idea is sound but there may be a math error or two.  I'm doing this from my phone.  :)

Comment: If you need derivatives to exist at the points, the problem is more complex.  You can fit a quadratic between each pair constrained on the derivative existing at the intersection at each data point.  Sounds a chore.  :)

Comment: Among many possible solutions, you can adapt the [Lagrange interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) to make the loop as differentiable as you like.